# Principal null Direction

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to understand what the principal null dierctions are in mathematics. Physicists define a principal null direction in a spacetime as a null vector which satisfies the Penrose-Debever equation. I would like to know what one   exactly means by principal null direction in a spacetime.